# Error in FTP connection using domain name, username and password?

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

I have following details only

domain name:Mydomain.com (I have not Server IP address)
UserId: abc
Password:123456

when I am  trying to connect ftp through Filezilla or Myftp it gives error like

Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: I had the same issue there was an issue with the internet connection and the port which I was given 21

Answer (score 145):

I had this error too. My domian name was a subdomain like xxx.yyy.com
And cpanel ftp configuration guided me that ftp server is ftp.xxx.yyy.com
Fillzilla was unable to connect and showed this error:

> Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor
>   servname provided, or not known".

This error is for dns resolving. I just removed "ftp." from ftp.xxx.yyy.com and it works now

Comment: This solved the problem. Simply remove ftp. from the front. Thanks.

Comment: "ftp" has been working for me for over a year, now it suddenly stopped. You are a legend. Quick and simple fix.

Comment: I had this problem.    I fixed it by changing the Encryption: selection to Use explicit FTP over TLS if available.    This must depend on the server requirements.

Comment: How is this the solution? But it works...

Answer (score 32):

Remove "ftp." from HOST name. e.g. if your website is http://www.example.com & you are using "ftp.example.com" then try with "example.com" only as host name.... it simply worked with me!

Comment: That's messed up and insane that this worked. What a joke GoDaddy is.

Answer (score 18):

It is Name resolution error. your domain name is not correct. Check for spelling mistakes or try using the IP address. You can use `ping mydomain.com` in windows to find out ip address of your server.

Answer (score 13):

It's likely you're using a service like GoDaddy (or similar) with cPanel setup. In my case, GoDaddy usually has this error and there's no way for me to "correctly" FTP using my domain.

The only way I've been able to fix this (strangely / stupidly) is to use your custom **cPanel IP address** and **NOT your `domain.com`, `ftp.domain.com` or domain IP address**

1. Take your **cPanel URL** from your cPanel FTP page:

   > https://abcabc123123.prod.ph12.secureserver.net:1234/cpsess1234567890/frontend/paper_lantern/ftp/accounts.html *(modified for privacy)*
2. Either use the **`abcabc123123.prod.ph12.secureserver.net` as your FTP domain**, OR get your **cPanel IP address** via ping:

   ```
   ping abcabc123123.prod.ph12.secureserver.net
   64 bytes from 123.456.789.123: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=32.398 ms
   ```

I hate that this works and my domain doesn't, but now I can FTP.

Comment: This is working, but I am in a / directory with .ftpquota as the only file and I can not go anywhere else

Answer (score 9):

## You can use the following methods

In my personal experience, these methods below really helps me dealing with ftp

- default port is `21`, make sure to check if your host port is also `21`.
- remove `ftp://` in the hostname.
- use hostname IP address, you can try both with and without `ftp://`.
- maybe the hostname is blocked in your country, try to use proxy or a VPN.
- Using Plain FTP(unsecure) may be a solution but it is **NOT RECOMMENDED** because it pose threats to your server.

Comment: removing ftp. from the hostname helped me to resolve the issu.e

Comment: removing ftp. from the hostname helped me too.thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had this error too. My domian name was a subdomain like xxx.yyy.com And cpanel ftp configuration guided me that ftp server is ftp.xxx.yyy.com Fillzilla was unable to connect and showed this error:

> Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

I have used IP address as ftp host rather than ftp.xxx.yyy.com

Comment: I had the same problem and when I used IP address as host, it worked.

Comment: Yeah it is very bizarre but I got mine to work using IP address too, domain won't work.

Answer (score 4):

For Godaddy & Filezilla,

- remove ftp from hostname and use domain. Example remove **ftp** from ftp.example.com and provide example.com as hostname
- Select Protocol - FTP
- Select Encryption - Only use plain FTP(insecure)

Try now!
Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Took me almost an hour to figure out, that leaving the port blank was the issue in my case. In Former times port 21 was used by default.

So setting `Port: 21` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a copy/paste problem...

Instead of copy/paste the URL and username, I remove all, and put it manually and it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Properly set up your dns records. Most of the times, this is the reason for error.
2. You will find your records at your hosing site. Put it from where you bought your domains.

This will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cpanel then just make a new ftp account and use the new account instead of your old one.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your Domain not resolves to your hosting. It usually occurs when you update you Name servers. it will short out automatically when Name server updation  completed. wait for you TTL.
If not Reset your  DNS Zone Management.